# css 2nd font style property not applying

Tags: html, css

I have set two font styling's in my css file, but for some reason the new one wont apply to the text in the html. The first .font-style I set works fine, but I can't get the second font-style property to apply.

**style.css**

```
.font-style {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Calibri, !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green !important;
}

.font-style-content-head {
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Calibri, !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black !important;
}
```

**This works:**

```
    <body>
        <div class="container-title">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col font-style">
                    @Model.Title
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**I cannot get this one to work:**

```
    <body>
        <div class="container-title">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col font-style-content-head">
                    @Model.Title
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't see any issue here, it works for second css class as well: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/5nug7ea2/23/

Comment: Remove the `,` after `Calibri`.

Comment: I don't  see any issue please add your code output from browser

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel removing the , fixed it.